# AWS lambda function python/pysparkl

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a lambda function that triggers when an object hits specific folder in s3 bucket and moves to different folder in the same s3 bucket.

But i am trying to modify the lambda function where the lambda triggers only if we receive all the mandatory files.(The existing lambda function i am having doesn't wait for other files ,triggers and  moves whenever new file is uploaded).

Could anybody help me out with this .

Answer (score 0):

Triggers do not function in this manner. S3 will trigger the lambda function for each file that is uploaded that matches the trigger definition as it is evaluated for every upload.

If it is a timing issue, you can use stop functions. S3 would trigger lambda. Lambda would trigger a step function that can wait X number of seconds/minutes/days. Then step functions will fire another trigger to do the operations on the S3 bucket.
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/?&trk=el_a131L000005unTnQAI&trkCampaign=pac_q2-04-2019_stepfunctions_tutorial_offering_link_2&sc_channel=el&sc_campaign=pac_q2-04-2019_stepfunctions_tutorial&sc_outcome=PaaS_Digital_Marketing&sc_geo=mult